# Проверка внутренностей DIV на наличие IMG с ID

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #div1,
    #div2 {
      min-width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    img.imgelem1 {
      width: 50px;
    }

    img.imgelem2 {
      width: 100px;
    }

    td {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="imgtd">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="imgelem1" src="img/1.png">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="imgelem2" src="img/2.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Проверить при нажатии кнопки на наличие определенной `img` в `div'е`
Например: 1 и 3 в 1 колонке, 2 и 4 в 2 колонке.
В Google не смог найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки есть ли элемент внутри можно использовать [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
const child = document.querySelector('#myImg')

const result = parent.contains(child)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <img id="myImg">
</div>
```